# Configuring the Webpack Dev Server for Angular html5mode

Tags: angularjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to enable html5mode in an Angular 1 application. This mode requires the webserver to return the same HTML for various paths. In nginx, this is done by adding a `try ... index.html` for the `location`, meaning nginx always fails back to the main html if it can't find the page.

However, while development I have no nginx, I'm using the Webpack dev server to serve the pages, with a proxy to the backend. How do I configure the Webpack dev server to behave in a similar fashion?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Oh dear. Oh dear oh dear oh dear.

I scanned the documentation twice, and only after posting this question I found the `historyApiFallback` settings, [as described here.](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver)

Add this to the settings:

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    proxy: { ... }
}
```

I'm keeping this question here hoping it will help others save time in the future.

Comment: Awesome :D I checked https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode but there is no option for webpack-dev-server

Comment: Life saver! Thanks a lot!